# Can I update view before action had executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

My ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project has a `Register` view in which I need to disable some elements immediately after model validation before corresponding action completes, because it is long operation.

I try to use `View(model).ExecuteResultAsync(ControllerContext)`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    IActionResult actionResult = null;

    if (model.Submitted = ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await View(model)?.ExecuteResultAsync(ControllerContext);
        //await PartialView("UserAccountSubmittedPartial")?.ExecuteResultAsync(ControllerContext);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.UserName))
        {
            model.UserName = UserManager.GenerateNewUserName();
        }

        BankApiUser newUser = new BankApiUser(model);
        IdentityResult identityResult = IdentityResult.Success;

        try
        {
            identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser, model.Password);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError() { Description = e.Message });
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            throw e;
        }

        if (identityResult?.Succeeded == true)
        {
            switch(model.LoginType)
            {
                case LoginType.LoginByUserName:
                    actionResult = RedirectToAction("Login", newUser);
                    break;

                case LoginType.LoginByEmail:
                    await EmailHelper.SendConfirmationLinkMail(HttpContext, model);
                    actionResult = View(model);
                    break;

                case LoginType.LoginByPhoneNumber:
                    await SmsHelper.SendVerificationCode(model);
                    actionResult = View(model);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actionResult = View(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        actionResult = View(model);
    }

    return actionResult;
}
```

In this case, scripts from the `Registry` view are not executed, and the contents of the view are displayed twice, one below the other.

I've also tried running only those scripts that update the form. To do this, I created a partial view containing these scripts and executed the `PartialViewResult` as shown above in the comments. As result I receive HTTP error 500 after `Register` action execution.

How can I update view using my scripts before `Register` action method completes?

---

I solved this problem by removing the form submit action in the controller and moving that logic into a javascript onsubmit event. (Thanks to @Brando Zhang) The model validation state and all other values that can only be calculated on the server side I get from the controller using ajax requests.

You can see the implementation in the solution repo: [BankAccountingPublic](https://github.com/pnfstas/BankAccountingPublic)

Comment: Could you please describe more details about what you want? Normally, we could pass some model result or tempdata to the view if the mode validation failed, then inside view we could generate the view according to the tempdata or the model result's specific property.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the following problem: After the submit action starts and before it completes, a form is shown to the user and all input elements are enabled. To prevent model and form change I'm trying to disable all input elements just after validation.

Comment: You mean you want to disable the form edit after clicking the submit button? If this is your requirement, I suggest you could consider using the JS to achieve your requirement, you could add disable attribute to all the textbox you want to disable and then use the ajax or form update to post the request. After getting the result from the server, you could use js to remove the disable attribute for all the textbox.

Comment: @Brando Zhang Yes, that's my goal. I can add a disable attribute from javascript but I only need to add it when ModelStatel.IsValid. To do this, I need to request the ModelStatel from the server. But I can't implement it correctly:  corresponding action starts earlier than jqXHR.done.

Comment: Have you consider using the client validation? The asp.net core also contain the client validation.

Comment: @Brando Zhang Yes, I use all the possibilities of client-side validation, but I think that is server validation is more powerfull.

Comment: But your requirement couldn't work for your codes, it's better you use client validation, besides, client validation contains the custom validation, you could also customize it and match your requirement, more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation).